# Настройка сборки для отдельного maven модуля

Tags: git, gitlab, teamcity

Добрый день.

Заголовок наверное не очень точно отражает суть вопроса, опишу лучше подробней.

Так исторически сложилось, что в одном git репозитории лежит несколько приложений.
Это maven проект, каждое отдельное приложение это свой модуль.

Воспрос - можно ли както настроить teamcity или gitlab, что бы следить за изменениями в отдельному модуле. Что бы не собирать parent и с ним все приложения, а собрать только нужные мне модули.

Может быть есть какойнить хук для git что бы наподобии smart commits использовать имя приложения в коммите(Например #App1) что бы teamcity понял, что нужно собирать данный моудль.

Есть еще одно ограничение, так исторически сложилось что есть несколько общих модулей, но изменения в общем модуле не всегда затрагивают все приложения(да не все гладко с организацией кода).

Answer (score 0):

есть такая возвожноcть.

1) для конфигурации перейти в настройки -> triggers -> Add new trigger -> vcs trigger.

теперь у нас есть возможность конфигурировать запуск, на какие изменения посмотреть. нам нужно добавить рулы. Нажимаем Add new rules

У нас появляется возможность обнаружить изменения по:

1. пользователю. Запускать билд и обнаружить изменения только определенных программеров
2. по комментарию. например, можно договориться о том, что комменты, начиная с #run запускают билд
3. изменениям по файлам. Запускать тогда и только тогда, когда в Module2 есть изменения. `**/Module2/**`

Стоит заметить, что мы увидим все коммиты, только желтым(те, что нас устраивают по рулу) будут подсвечиваться только нужные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другое решение.

для кадлого модуля создать отдельные